# Setup Cockpit to work with Nginx Proxy Manager

Tags: reverse-proxy, cockpit

We have the network setup per below

1/ Ubuntu server with Cockpit at 192.179.10.101. Cockpit is accessible at https://192.168.1.101:9090

2/ Nginx proxy manager is at 192.168.10.102

3/ We have setup a domain name, for the purpose of this sample, abc.com. We setup dns forwarding is, https://cockpit.abc.com to access our cockpit from outside

4/ We setup the NPM to forward from cockpit.abc.com to 192.168.1.101:9090 and using SSL let's encrypt as well

5/ We modify the cocpit.conf to be proxy aware, follow this article

https://garrett.github.io/cockpit-project.github.io/external/wiki/Proxying-Cockpit-over-NGINX

6/ If we use the internal ip e.g. 192.168.1.101:9090 , we can access cockpit from inside network

7/ If we use cockpit.abc.com, we have error as TLS handshake fail and a warning is recieved. This error means, after checking, the cockpit still is not proxy aware yet...

Are we missing any other step to make cockpit accessible from outside, via cockpit.abc.com?

Thank you